# Convolution of multiple correlated probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convolution

Following up [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15024/convolution-of-multiple-probability-density-functions), assume $X_1$ to $X_n$ are $n$ correlated random variables with know marginal cumulative/probability distribution functions of $f_1(X_1)$ to $f_n(X_n)$, and a joint cumulative/probability density function of $f(X_1, ..., X_n)$.

What is the cumulative/probability density function of $y=X_1+...+X_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One convolution formula is:

$$f_Y(y) = \iint\!\!\ddots\!\!\iint_{\Bbb R^{n-1}} f\left(x_1, x_2 , x_3, \ldots,x_{n-1}, y-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k\right)\operatorname d x_{n-1} \cdots \operatorname d x_1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please also help me with the case that I only have the joint cumulative distribution function?